# Google App Engine: Failed to Upload Repository (403: Forbidden)

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I've just started using the [Google App Engine with IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-google-app-engine.html) on Arch Linux.

I've created a local clone of the tutorial repository on my machine, made a small change to it, and I'm attempting to upload the project back onto the server. This results in the following error:

```
Post https://us.gcr.io/v2/foo/appengine/default.bar/blobs/uploads/: token auth attempt for registry: https://us.gcr.io/v2/token?account=_token&scope=repository%3Afoo%2Fappengine%2Fdefault.bar%3Apush%2Cpull&service=us.gcr.io request failed with status: 403 Forbidden
ERROR
ERROR: error pushing image "us.gcr.io/foo/appengine/default.bar:latest": exit status 1
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

I've tried authenticating my computer via browser login using `gcloud auth login` but hasn't resolved the problem. I've manually generated a key, but I'm unaware of how to register this using the gcloud tool?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You know the giant banner telling you to start the free trial with a complementary $300 credit? It helps if you click it. D'oh!

(I simply hadn't activated the service!)